# UIButton rotation animation not rotating back with CGAffineTransformMakeRotation

Tags: objective-c, animation, objective-c-blocks, cgaffinetransform

I have a button (openMenu) that I am animating down (works fine) and rotate (works the first time) with a "drawer".  The first time it rotates it works.. but when I try to rotate again it wigs out and hides the image and shows the button title?  Any ideas of why? I need it to just rotate back another 45 degrees. Don't know why it would do this.

Also - see GIF image below so you see what is happening.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    draw1 = 0;
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -200, 768, 200);
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(768, 200)];
    openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(680, 100, 55, 55);

}




- (IBAction)openMenu:(id)sender {

    if (draw1 == 0) {

        draw1 = 1;

        CGRect optionsDrawer = scrollView.frame;
        CGRect optionsButton = openMenu.frame;
        optionsDrawer.origin.y += 200;
        optionsButton.origin.y += 200;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                         animations:^{
                             scrollView.frame = optionsDrawer;
                             openMenu.frame = optionsButton;
                             openMenu.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(45));
                         }];
    } else {

        draw1 = 0;

        CGRect optionsDrawer = scrollView.frame;
        CGRect optionsButton = openMenu.frame;
        optionsDrawer.origin.y -= 200;
        optionsButton.origin.y -= 200;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                         animations:^{
                             scrollView.frame = optionsDrawer;
                             openMenu.frame = optionsButton;
                             openMenu.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(45));
                         }];
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: If I change openMenu.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2); for the first one and openMenu.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2); it works! BUT! That is rotating is 180 degrees.  When I do -M_PI / 4, it has the same issue as above. I don't know why this just isn't working with 45 degrees rotations?!

Comment: Shouldn't you rotate it back to 0 degrees?

Answer (score 3):

Do like this, i am using layers to animate, it is easy, once u rotate, dont  need to rotate again, just brings back to original state. I did like this it works for me, just try this. 
since i am using layers add "QuartzCore" library and import this

```
 #import<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> //include this

 if (draw1 == 0) 
 { 
    ....//your code
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
     detailButton.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation((180) * 45, 0, 0, 1);
 }];

 } 
 else
 {

 ....//your code

   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
    detailButton.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity; //brings back to original position by animating
}];


}
```

hope this helps u :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate the button back - you need to provide negative number as the value for CGAffineTransformMakeRotation().

Here is the snippet from Apple Docs:

> CGAffineTransformMakeRotation()
>
> Returns an affine transformation matrix constructed from a rotation
> value you provide.
>
> CGAffineTransform CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (    CGFloat angle );
>
> The angle, in radians, by which this matrix rotates
> the coordinate system axes. In iOS, a positive value specifies
> counterclockwise rotation and a negative value specifies clockwise
> rotation. In OS X, a positive value specifies clockwise rotation and a
> negative value specifies counterclockwise rotation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've tried doing this in the above code. I am already converting to radians.

Comment: If I do openMenu.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2); to rotate and openMenu.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2); to "reverse it" it works. But that is 180 degrees... i need 45 degrees. If i do M_PI / 4 it doesn't work at all?